# Angular dirrectives and ng-class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-class

Suppose a directive with html e.g. in `component.html` like

```
<div class="text-field"
     ng-class="{'classA': varA}">
....
</div>
```

then I'm trying to do...

```
<component ng-class="{'classB': varB}"></component>
```

After that in `ng-class` I'm having something like `{'classB': varB} {'classA': varA}` that is obviously not working.

The problem is that I cannot change `component.html` but I need to add/remove class on keyup (depending on criteria). Is it possible to add ng-class in my situation or mayb there's another way to add/remove class?

Comment: Does the directive have `replace:true`? Can you explain what exactly you're trying to achieve from this?

Comment: @TJ I'm trying to achieve `ng-class="{'classB': varB, 'classA': varA}"` or another way to add/remove `classB`. And there's no `replace:true` in component.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding another directive that adds the class via script, something like

```
.directive('myDir',function(){
  return {
    scope:{
     varB:'='
    },
    link: function($scope,$element){
      if($scope.varB)
        $element.addClass('classB');
    }
  }
});
```

and use like:

```
<component ng-class="{'classB': varB}" my-dir var-b="something"></component>
```